# xml parsing with no browser use

Tags: android

I have read the example for Rss Parsing from the ibm site.(http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/).

In this example,the rss are shown in a listview and then,if you press one announcement you can see it in the web browser of the device.How could i see them in the app,with no use of the device browser?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout with a `WebView` then load the URL from each "announcement" using [`WebView.loadUrl`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!Do you have any tutorial on that?

Comment: Well, not personally, I haven't made one on it yet. But I think a lot of stuff has been written about it. I believe the link I gave you in my answer has an example about using `loadUrl()`.

Comment: ok.I have found a "HelloWebView" tutorial!But in this way,i see all the page,including the logo of the site etc..What i have to do in order to see only the announcement?this is my "big" question...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused but you seem to have answered your own question.

You say you don't want to use the web browser on the device but the example in your question doesn't use the browser. It does exactly what you're asking for.

The idea is that you download the html from the website and then use the parser to break it up into separate "announcements" and store them in list view items in your program.

I have done a bit of this type of thing myself in android. I used [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) java library, which makes breaking the html into the bits you want to display really easy.

If you want some more help I can give you an example of an app I made that pulls movie times from google.com/movies as an example. here are links to the classes where I did the html download and parse:

[ScreenScraper.java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11634324/Movie%20Times/src/adhd/movee/ScreenScraper.java)

[HtmlParser.java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11634324/Movie%20Times/src/adhd/movee/HtmlParser.java)